# jQuery.simpleDialog box not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get a "simpleDialog" box to open up via a link using the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.simpledialog').simpleDialog();
});

jQuery('#sdHc2').simpleDialog({
  showCloseLabel: false
});

});
</script>
```

Here's the link I'm using:

```
<a href="#" id="sdHc2" class="medium" rel="simpleDialog2">request a call back</a>
```

And the div I want to display:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="simpleDialog2">
 <h3>Form content</h3>
 <p>This is where the form will go.</p>
 <a href="#" class="close">close</p></a>
</div>
```

I've called the jquery.simpledialog.js script in the head along with the jquery.simpledialog.css but for some reason the dialog box is not showing up.

I have a show/hide script running on the page which works fine so what am I missing to get the dialog box to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra set of `})` tags in there, meaning you're a) getting and error and b) `jQuery('#sdHc2')` isn't running on `document.ready`, it should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.simpledialog').simpleDialog();
    jQuery('#sdHc2').simpleDialog({
      showCloseLabel: false
    });
});
```

---

I would simplify it overall with a common class on the links though, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="medium dialogLink" rel="simpleDialog2">request a call back</a>
```

Then bind them all at once instead of per-`id` like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.dialogLink').simpleDialog({
      showCloseLabel: false
    });
});
```

This way you don't have to change your code at all as you add links, just add as many link/dialog pairs in the page as you want.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I actually went down the route of simplifying the coding as I realise I was trying to over complicate things! :)

Comment: On a side-note, I have a form in my div now and want to close the overlay when the form is sent (using external send script)